# Optimization problem (total distance from point on sphere to other points)?

Tags: optimization, constraints

Let $M_i(x_i, y_i, z_i)$ be a set of $n$ fixed points. Given their coordinates, find a point $M(x, y, z)$ which is on the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and has the minimal sum of distances between itself and the given $n$ points.

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \|M - M_i\| \rightarrow \min_{M} \\
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1
$$

At first I mistakingly determined the problem to be convex and wanted to go the common way: "show convexity, show strong duality, use KKT to find extremum". However, Michael C. Grant was quick enough to point out the problem is not convex. I would be grateful for any hints on how to solve it then.

I tried moving to dual problem (which is always convex) but got stuck:

$$
L(M, \nu) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \|M - M_i\| + \nu (\|M\|^2 - 1) \\
\nabla_M L(M, \nu) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{M - M_i}{\|M - M_i \|} + 2\nu M = 0
$$

Can't even get $M$ out of the last line$\dots$

Comment: Your problem is not, in fact, convex. The constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ is not convex. The unit sphere is not a convex set. The unit *ball*, described by $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$, is convex, but it is clear from your model you don't want that.

Comment: @MichaelC.Grant oh, I see. Totally forgot that the convexity of the target function alone is not enough. Obviously, no Slater condition now, any hints to solve it then? Move to dual problem (which is always convex)?

Comment: Are you trying to come up with a formula or an algorithm for finding the optimal solution?

Comment: @user2566092 formula. This is not a programming assignment. This is a pen-and-paper task.

Comment: If your objective function was the sum-of-squared euclidean distances then I'm pretty sure the answer would be the mean of the $M_i$ vectors scaled to the unit sphere. However your function is the sum of unsquared distances, and I'm not sure what happens in that case.

Comment: @user2566092 Stephen Boyd "Convex Optimization" page 131 says that if you apply a monotone increasing function (quare root in this case) to your target function or constraints, then the resulting problem is equivalent to the original. Care to elaborate on your solution then?

Comment: That's not relevant here: you're not applying a function to the whole objective, but separately to different pieces of the objective.  It's not at all the same problem.

Comment: Case in point: suppose two of the fixed points are at the north pole and one at the south pole.  The sum of the squared distances is maximized by a point at the south pole; the sum of the distances is minimized at angle $2 \arctan(2)$ from the north pole, if my calculations are correct.

Comment: The dual problem is always convex, but it's quite unlikely you will have strong duality, which means you won't get a solution to your original problem from it.

Answer (score 1):

Although, this doesn't answers your question, I'm writing the solution for a slightly different problem.

As mentioned in the comments, your problem is not convex. But if you change your objective a little bit you can find a simple solution.

Let's solve the following problem instead:

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{n} \|M - M_i\|^2_2 \rightarrow \min_{M} \\
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1
$$

Here, the objective is sum of the squared differences, and the used norm is $L_2$ norm. Then you can write it as:

$$
\text{minimize}_M ~~\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (M - M_i)^T(M - M_i)\\
\text{subject to} \\
M^TM = 1
$$

Note that $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} (M - M_i)^T(M - M_i)=nM^TM-(2\sum_i M_i)^TM+\sum_i M_i^TM_i$.

So, you can equivalently solve:

$$
\text{minimize}_M ~~ nM^TM-(2\sum_i M_i)^TM\\
\text{subject to} \\
M^TM = 1
$$

Since $M^TM = 1$, you basically want the solution of the following problem:

$$
M^*=\arg\max~~ (\sum_i M_i)^TM\\
\text{subject to} \\
M^TM = 1
$$

If you fix the magntude of $M$, $(\sum_i M_i)^TM$ has the maximum value if the direction of $M$ is the same as $\sum_i M_i$. Therefore the solution is:

$$
M^*=\frac{\sum_i M_i}{\|\sum_i M_i\|_2}
$$